# django_admin_log has not been created for me

Tags: database, django, configuration

I am using Django version 1.5.4 and I followed the instructions here

http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/models.html

But I cannot find django_admin_log table.

I manually deleted rango.db from

```
C:\Users\Glowie\django\tango_with_django_project
```

The INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py looks like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'rango',
)
```

I executed the command

```
PS C:\users\Glowie\django\tango_with_django_project> python manage.py syncdb
```

Which outputs:

```
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table rango_category
Creating table rango_page
```

And then asks me to define a superuser, which I do each time .....

```
You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no):
```

Which outputs

```
Superuser created successfully.
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

Then I run the command

```
PS C:\users\Glowie\django\tango_with_django_project> python manage.py sql rango
```

Which outputs

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "rango_category" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
;
CREATE TABLE "rango_page" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "category_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "rango_category" ("id"),
    "title" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    "url" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "views" integer NOT NULL
)
;

COMMIT;
```

But where is django_admin_log table. The text says

> You should see that the table django_admin_log is created for you.
>   Once done, open your project’s urls.py file. This was created in the
>   project configuration directory.

Where will I find django_admin_log?
Please tell me where is "project configuration directory".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django_admin_log` is a table that was created when you ran `python manage.py syncdb`. It's showing in the terminal output you posted that displayed after you ran `syncdb`:

```
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table django_admin_log  <---RIGHT HERE
Creating table rango_category
Creating table rango_page
```

That table isn't really important to worry about now that it's actually created. The real key for you is to find your `urls.py` in your project configuration directory.

Your project configuration directory is a directory within your project directory that has the same name as your project directory. From earlier in the [Tango with Django tutorial](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/setup.html#creating-your-django-project):

> You’ll now notice within your workspace is a directory set to the name
>   of your new project, tango_with_django_project. Within this newly
>   created directory, you should see two items:
>
> - **another directory with the same name as your project, tango_with_django_project**; and
> - a Python script called manage.py.
>
> **For the purposes of this tutorial, we call this nested directory the
>   project configuration directory**. Within this directory, you will find
>   four Python scripts. We will discuss this scripts in detail later on,
>   but for now you should see:

Thus, based on your directory structure, your project configuration directory is located at:

```
PS C:\users\Glowie\django\tango_with_django_project\tango_with_django_project>
```

and the tutorial wants you to open the `urls.py` file within that directory.